# What to do when IFT doesn't work

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, implicit-function-theorem

I am trying to solve a question and I am stuck on something.

Consider the equations:$$e^{x}+y^{2}z=2,\ \ xy+2y+\frac{1}{z^{2}}=3$$I should find (i) If there exists a neighborhood of (0,1,1) such that these equations define x,z as a differentiable function of y. (ii) same thing but x,y as a function of z.

So I defined $$G\left(x,y,z\right)=\begin{pmatrix}e^{x}+y^{2}z-2\\
xy+2y+\frac{1}{z^{2}}-3
\end{pmatrix}$$ and found out that $\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial G_{1}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial G_{1}}{\partial z}\\
\frac{\partial G_{2}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial G_{2}}{\partial z}
\end{pmatrix}$ is invertible and thus, the function we want exists. For (ii) it came out that $\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial G_{1}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial G_{1}}{\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial G_{2}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial G_{2}}{\partial y}
\end{pmatrix}$ is not invertible and so I can't use the implicit function theorem. How one goes on from here? I tried to show that if I fix $z=1$ I got couple of solutions to:$$e^{x}+y^{2}=2,\ \ xy+2y=2$$ In a every neighborhood of (0,1,1) but it didn't work. How can one prove a function of this sort exist or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be no such differentiable functions $x(z)$ and $y(z)$, since if they existed you could differentiate the identity $G \bigl( x(z),y(z),z \bigr) = (0,0)^T$ to get
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
e^x & 2yz \\
y & x+2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x'(z) \\ y'(z)
\end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
y^2 \\
-2/z^3
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
,
$$
which at the point $(0,1,1)$ becomes
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x'(1) \\ y'(1)
\end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
-2
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
,
$$
a contradiction.

Comment: ohhhh, I actually got to that point and didn't see the contradiction, didn't realize the matrix multiplication on the left gives the same equation twice. thank you very much!